# IndentationError in Python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this block of code which looks indented but fails to run. I get the below error:

```
File "./cloneRepos.py", line 16
    for line in f:
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Code is as follows:

```
def cloneRepos(dirPath,reposListFile):
    with open(reposListFile,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            s=line.split(".git")    #Splits based on .git into two halves

            x=s[0].split("/")       #Splits the string based on that character

            repoName=x[-1]          #Gets the last element in the array

            repo = clone_repository(line, dirPath) # Clones a non-bare repository line is repoUrl and dirPath is repository path

            print repoName

            print line
```

Comment: This can happen if you mix tabs and spaces in the file. Make sure all tabs are gone.

Comment: I thought tabs is the standard way to follow

Comment: @Zack, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says spaces is preferred but to follow the same style as any legacy code. I generally prefer tabs to spaces so will use them if I'm working on something only I am ever going to use.

Answer (score 0):

I used two tabs instead of one and then it worked! What is the best practice to follow w.r.t python indentation? Should we use tabs or spaces? I am new to python !

Comment: it's usually 4 spaces per indentation - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: It can be tabs or spaces (most use spaces) but don't mix the two!